# Php microtime() is not working on live site. Looking for workaround

Tags: php, wordpress, hash, uniqueidentifier, microtime

I have Zend Server 6.3 and Php 5.4 on Windows. And system works very well. Now I moved code to live site, which runs Php 5.3.29 on Ubuntu Server with DirectAdmin. All other website are running well there. But my current website gives me this error (the site is on WordPress 4.3):

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch.
Headers:50541 Library:50623 in /home/cheapauto/domains/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1482
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/*USER*/domains/*DOMAIN*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/*MY-PLUGIN*/includes/final.class.NRSBooking.php on line 101
```

The line is this:

```
$now = explode(' ', microtime())[1];
```

And my whole plugin function is this:

```
private function getIncrementalHash($length = 5)
{
    //$charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPRSTUVYZ"; // fits LT & EN, O is skipped to similarity to Zero
    $charsetLength = strlen($charset);
    $result = '';

    $now = explode(' ', microtime())[1];
    while ($now >= $charsetLength)
    {
        $i = $now % $charsetLength;
        $result = $charset[$i] . $result;
        $now /= $charsetLength;
    }
    return substr($result, -$length);
}
```

Any ideas how to make it work on live site?

As per Php reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php
it says:

> microtime() returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds. This
>   function **is only available on operating systems that support the**
>   **gettimeofday() system call.**

And I use that function to generate unique new booking code:

```
$newBookingCode = "R".$validNextMySQLInsertId."A".$this->getIncrementalHash(5);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Php version on your server?

Comment: Php 5.3.29 is on server.

Comment: Not really a very good testing environment if it has a different version of PHP especially if the test environment has a newer version of PHP that the LIVE environment

Comment: PHP 5.3 has been past its [end of life](http://php.net/eol.php) for over 1 year. Maybe it's time to upgrade both test environment and server if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array dereferencing, i.e. getting results from function which returns array like:

```
$now = explode(' ', microtime())[1];
```

is available since **php5.4**

For **php5.3** and older use:

```
$now = explode(' ', microtime());
$now = $now[1];
```

Comment: Just for completeness the PHP5.3 code will work in all newer versions of PHP